# How to limit Internet surfing to Chrome in Windows 11?

Tags: windows, browser, internet, windows-11

How can I make Chrome the only allowed browser on my Windows 11 Home Edition PC?

-Simply uninstalling other browsers or blocking their download would not be enough because a simple browser could always be coded and run via the command prompt.

-I cannot disable the command prompt because I need it to download libraries since I am learning programming, and eventually, I'd still need it for work.

-I cannot simply allow internet connection only to Chrome because other applications that are not browsers need internet access. CMD needs internet, and if I take internet away from CMD, then I won't be able to download libraries.

I specifically need a solution that only allows Chrome as a browser to surf the internet. What could that solution be?

Comment: practically what's your goal, and *who* are you trying to stop? Anything you can do, you can undo.

Comment: Part 1: If the solution is to be found in system settings or other programs, that would not be a problem because I can block access to those programs or settings via a combination of reigstry editor policies and an apllication called Cold Turkey.

Comment: Part 2: Who controls the machine is not a problem. I have my standard account and and an administrator account. I can access the administrator account only once the time I set with the COld Turkey app is off the reason being that when the the block by cold turkey goes off , then i can access a  password manager that contains the password to access my administrator account.

Comment: Part 3: This is to say that if the solution requires control by someone else that is the administrator , than that would be a welcomed solution because i have access to that but at the same time that possibility only unlocks when I plan it to unlock.So that's good.

Comment: Who am I trying to stop? Myself

Comment: What are you trying to stop yourself  *from*?

Comment: Surfing the web via a newly coded browser executed with the cmd.

Comment: If you're going to spend all the effort to do that, well, you're not going to stop yourself.

Comment: Is there a technical solution that can limit surfing to a specified browser like chrome?

Comment: Generally speaking, trying to find _a technical solution to a social problem_ is not the right way of addressing the issue. More specifically: here you hold the 'keys to the kingdom'- so any technical measure you put in place can be subverted by yourself by dint of effort. What I think Geek is getting at is: if you can spend the effort to 'code a new browser', you can also spend the effort to boot in safe mode (or whatever) to work around whatever technical restriction you put in place

Comment: I understand but I have other ways to prevent other methods of bypass. For example Safe Booting is restricted on my machine by a boot password which is stored into a password manager. As for "keys to the kingdom" I suppose you are referring to the fact that I am administrator,right? Well I have an administrator account and a standard account. The password to access the administrator account is also stored in my password manager and access to that password manager is regulated by the "Cold Turkey Blocker".

Comment: Once the block is lifted from Cold turkey, only then I can acces the password and the admini passords or the UEFI settings password. I understand that the solution might not be ultimate but that would be better than nothing.

Comment: Also I am not really capable of coding a new browser. I am still learning but for something like that chatgtp can help. I have created simple browsers with chagtp

Comment: By keys to the kingdom I mean you are ultimately in control - anything you can do, you can also undo. I saw what you said about "cold turkey blocker" and accounts. I believe this question as asked should be narrowly answerable (though I don't know what mechanisms Windows offers for this), but in my view that would be the right answer to the wrong question- this feels like a classic _'XY problem'_